# Fill cells with colors using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am currently using openpyxl v2.2.2 for Python 2.7 and i wanted to set colors to cells. I have used the following imports

```
import openpyxl,
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
```

and the following is the code I tried using:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000',
                   end_color='FFFF0000',
                   fill_type='solid')

ws['A1'].style = redFill
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  self.font = value.font.copy()
AttributeError: 'PatternFill' object has no attribute 'font'
```

Any idea on how to set cell A1 (or any other cells) with colors using openpyxl?

Comment: Could you provide the full trace back

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to assign a fill object to a style.

`ws['A1'].fill = redFill` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I'm quite new to Python and the openpyxl docs were not clear about how to apply the fill to a cell. Your answer has solved the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this to a selection of columns, IE A1:A5?

Comment: @CallamDelaney see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66074706/4094231

Answer (score 18):

The API for styles changed once again.  What worked for me was

```
my_red = openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(rgb='00FF0000')
my_fill = openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=my_red)
cell.fill = my_fill
```

Color is an alpha RGB hex color. You can pass it in as `'rrggbb'` with a default alpha of 00 or specify the alpha with `'aarrggbb'`. A bunch of colors are defined as constants in `openpyxl.styles.colors` if you need to grab one quickly.

Comment: my_fill = openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=my_red)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.  They changed things and most of the help you see on the internet is for older versions of the openpyxl library from what I am seeing.

```
# Change background color 
xls_cell.style = Style(fill=PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                                        fill_type='solid', 
                                        fgColor=Color('C4C4C4')))
```

Comment: Something to be careful about.  If you make multiple changes to the cell previous changes are wiped away with the most recent changes.  If you want to make say 6 changes, you have to do all 6 in the same command.  You can not change them one by one.  If you do only the last change will persist.

Answer (score 7):

in python 3.x

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000',
                   end_color='FFFF0000',
                   fill_type='solid')
ws['A1'].fill = redFill
```

that working but i dont know in python 2.x i hope working
just put `ws['A1'].fill=redFill`

Comment: To make PatternFill work you need `from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill`

Answer (score 7):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

_file_name = "Test.xlsx"
_sheet_name = "Test_Sheet"

def new_workbook(_file_name, _sheet_name):
    wb = Workbook()  # Workbook Object
    ws = wb.active  # Gets the active worksheet
    ws.title = _sheet_name  # Name the active worksheet

    # Writing the header columns
    ws['A1'] = 'Name'
    ws['B1'] = 'Class'
    ws['C1'] = 'Section'
    ws['D1'] = 'Marks'
    ws['E1'] = 'Age'
    

    col_range = ws.max_column  # get max columns in the worksheet

    # formatting the header columns, filling red color
    for col in range(1, col_range + 1):
        cell_header = ws.cell(1, col)
        cell_header.fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type="solid") #used hex code for red color

    wb.save(_file_name)  # save the workbook
    wb.close()  # close the workbook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_workbook(_file_name, _sheet_name)
```

## Result - [image]

Answer (score 5):

What I would do for Excel is this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws["A1"].fill = PatternFill("solid", start_color="FFA500")
```

You can replace "A1" with another cell and start_color has to be a hex color.

Answer (score 4):

To fill a range of rows/columns, do this

```
for cell in ws['A1:A100']:
   cell[0].fill = redFill
```

To fill all rows of a column

```
for cell in ws['A1:{}'.format(ws.max_row)]:
   cell[0].fill = redFill
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested for loop to fill a two dimensional range.

Python 3.9

```
import openpyxl as op
fill_gen = op.styles.PatternFill(fill_type='solid',
                                 start_color='FFFFFF',
                                 end_color='FFFFFF')
for row in ws["A1:BB50"]:
    for cell in row:
        cell.fill = fill_gen
```