# Pandas edit excel cell color

Tags: python, pandas

I have a block of code that reads in a sql query.

```
import pandas as pd


Report_results = pd.read_sql_query(Assignment_Query, con=mydb)
```

I know this block works, as I can see the data pulled and it is written to an excel file, xlsx to be specific, just fine. What I can't figure out how to do is apply a simple color to the pulled data. I've looked through the pandas documentation and multiple tutorials, but can't seem to get it to work. This is what I tried

```
Report_results = pd.style.apply(color_negative_red)
```

colr_negative_red is simply

```
def color_negative_red(value):
    color = 'red'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Again, I know that the data is pulled correctly, I just can't figure out how to change the color of the data before it is written to the excel file.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color when displayed in your editor or in excel?

Comment: I'm trying to change the color in the Excel sheet

Comment: look at using `openpyxl`

Comment: Per Chris's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30484220/10416673