# How to fill color to cell using Python

Tags: python, excel

[image]

I have this excel file, how to search cell have "-->" character then fill color for it
I try research but all are solution for DataFrame is available

Comment: did you try anything? What did you try? What's wrong with DataFrame solution you found?  conversely why can't you just use conditional formatting in Excel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30486164/5386938

Comment: @JeffUK I tried use Conditional Formatting but don't know how to set value for value property .. I just saw value is number. Ex:
 `worksheet.conditional_format('A1', {'type':     'cell',
                                    'criteria': 'greater than',
                                    'value':     5,
                                    'format':    red_format})`

Comment: I don't know what I need type for value property -  @JeffUK

Comment: In Excel itself you can also check for substrings with: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-->", E2))`

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the presence of any character in the string, use the ***SEARCH*** function in the ***ISNUMBER*** function.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-->", E2))
```

This will return ***True*** if E2 contains "-->".

And then you can fill color in excel sheet's cell.

After that use **PatternFill** to color cell as follows:

```
pattern_fill = PatternFill(patterntype = 'solid', fgcolor = 'C64747')

worksheet['E2'].fill = pattern_fill
```

patterntype, fgcolor data can be used as per requirement.